# WSAIoctl function to control the packets send speed of a UDP socket

Tags: c++, windows, udp, qos

Could I use the `WSAIoctl()` function provided by the Windows SDK to control the packets send speed of a UDP socket?

I need to control the packets sending speed of an UDP socket at the accuracy of 400KB/S. I am running program at Windows 7 System.

I have tried to use the `Sleep()` API provided by Windows SDK to control the number of UDP packets sended in a little time slice. But I have also found that when my program called `Sleep(1)`, the thread in which the `Sleep(1)` function always slept more than 1 ms. So this solution cannot control the UDP packets' sending speed at the level of accuracy which I need.

My mentor has told me that I could try to use the `WSAIoctl()` API so as to set the `SIO_SET_QOS` option in order to solve this problem. But I cannot find enough information about `SIO_SET_QOS`.

Comment: Sorry ,  English is not my native language. So Please forgive my if my description has some mistakes.

Comment: It's documented, but your 'mentor' isn't correct about this. You can't control the rate of sending from the UDP stack, and SIO_SET_QOS has nothing to do with that whatsoever: it's an instruction to the *routers*.

Comment: So do you have some more information about the SIO_SET_QOS in detail? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Yes, and I have already provided it: 'it is documented'. Have a look on MSDN where you found `WSAIoctl()`.

Comment: Thanks again, I have found it.